# How can I call the git clean -df command from a python script

Tags: python, git

I am new to python and trying to use git commands in python script.
The requirement is that I need to call some git commands like git clean and git reset commands in my python script. I need to use subprocess for this as I can't use any external libraries like GitPython.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: `subprocess.run(["git", "clean", "-df"])`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it like below

```
import shlex
import subprocess 

command= "git clean -df" # you can paste any command here
comm=shlex.split(command) # This will convert the command into list format

proc=Popen(comm) # This will execute your command
```

for more detailed information , refer here

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: Thank you so much. This was simpler than I expected it to be.